# SVG Transform Origin CSS Animation – Firefox Bug

Tags: css, animation, firefox, svg, transform

Trying to get an SVG/CSS animation working cross-browser. I am aware of [this firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=891074), but strangely using `transform-box: fill-box;` solves the problem in one instance, but not the other.

See the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/skqmmv75/1/), one gear spins properly from the center whereas the second does not (only in Firefox, Chrome and Safari works properly).

--

I'm using the following CSS structure:

```
#gear-large {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation: spin 9.905s linear infinite;
}
```

to transform an SVG `<g>`group containing a `<path>`:

```
<g id="gear-large">
 <path d="M110.8,68.5l4.9-2.4a.9.9,0,0,0,.5-1l-.8-4.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.8-.7l-5.4-.6a.9.9,0,0,1-.7-.6,32.7,32.7,0,0,0-1.6-3.7.9.9,0,0,1,.1-.9l3.4-4.3a.9.9,0,0,0,0-1.1l-2.5-3.5a.9.9,0,0,0-1-.3l-5.1,1.8a.9.9,0,0,1-.9-.2,32.2,32.2,0,0,0-3.1-2.8.9.9,0,0,1-.3-.9l1.1-5.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.4-1l-3.8-2.1a.9.9,0,0,0-1.1.2l-3.8,3.8a.9.9,0,0,1-.9.2l-4-1.1a.9.9,0,0,1-.7-.7l-1.2-5.2a.9.9,0,0,0-.8-.7L77.4,31a.9.9,0,0,0-.9.6l-1.7,5a.9.9,0,0,1-.7.6l-4.1.7a.9.9,0,0,1-.9-.3l-3.3-4.1a.9.9,0,0,0-1-.3l-4,1.7a.9.9,0,0,0-.5.9l.6,5.2a.9.9,0,0,1-.4.9,32.7,32.7,0,0,0-3.4,2.5.9.9,0,0,1-.9.1l-4.7-2.2a.9.9,0,0,0-1,.2l-2.9,3.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.1,1.1L50,51.2a.9.9,0,0,1,0,1l-1.1,1.9-.9,1.9a.9.9,0,0,1-.8.5H41.9a.9.9,0,0,0-.8.6l-1.2,4.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.4,1l4.4,2.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.4.9,32.5,32.5,0,0,0-.2,4.2.9.9,0,0,1-.5.8l-4.7,2.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.5,1l.8,4.3a.9.9,0,0,0,.8.7l5.2.6a.9.9,0,0,1,.7.6,33,33,0,0,0,1.6,3.9.9.9,0,0,1-.1.9L45,89.4a.9.9,0,0,0,0,1.1L47.6,94a.9.9,0,0,0,1,.3l5-1.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.9.2,32.2,32.2,0,0,0,3.2,2.8.9.9,0,0,1,.3.9l-1.1,5.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.4,1l3.8,2.1a.9.9,0,0,0,1.1-.2l3.8-3.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.9-.2l4,1.1a.9.9,0,0,1,.7.7l1.2,5.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.8.7l4.3.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.9-.6l1.8-5.1a.9.9,0,0,1,.7-.6l4-.7a.9.9,0,0,1,.9.3l3.4,4.2a.9.9,0,0,0,1,.3l4-1.7a.9.9,0,0,0,.5-.9l-.6-5.4a.9.9,0,0,1,.4-.9A32.4,32.4,0,0,0,98.4,95a.9.9,0,0,1,.9-.1l4.9,2.3a.9.9,0,0,0,1-.2l2.9-3.3a.9.9,0,0,0,.1-1.1L105.3,88a.9.9,0,0,1,0-.9l1-1.7.9-1.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.8-.5h5.5a.9.9,0,0,0,.8-.6l1.2-4.2a.9.9,0,0,0-.4-1l-4.6-2.9a.9.9,0,0,1-.4-.9,32.2,32.2,0,0,0,.2-4A.9.9,0,0,1,110.8,68.5ZM92.7,77.1a16.1,16.1,0,1,1-6.5-21.9A16.1,16.1,0,0,1,92.7,77.1Z" transform="translate(-0.3)" fill="none" stroke="#00b7d6" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2.4" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</g>
```

Comment: My question is not about the w3c specification @RobertLongson, rather it is about implementing a transform-origin on an SVG object and the problems that have arisen in doing so across browsers.

Comment: I have solved this issue on my end, but thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `transform-origin` to work cross-browser, you cannot use percentage values.  The way Chrome interprets percentage values is out-of-date and does not follow the current spec.

The fix for now is to use absolute coordinates instead.

Even if you are happy with it only working on Chrome, your SVG is likely to break in the future when Chrome fixes their behaviour.

```css
#gear-large {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 77.7px 69.7px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 77.7px 69.7px;
  transform-origin: 77.7px 69.7px;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation: spin 9.905s linear infinite;
    fill: #FAFAFA;
  stroke: #00b7d6;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  stroke-width: 2.4;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#gear-small {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 29.75px 32.85px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 29.75px 32.85px;
  transform-origin: 29.75px 32.85px;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  animation: spin-reverse 5.66s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  
  0% {
      -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    
    
  }
}



@keyframes spin-reverse {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="437" height="285" viewBox="0 0 437 285">

<g id="gear-large-wrapper">
    <g id="gear-large">
     <path d="M110.8,68.5l4.9-2.4a.9.9,0,0,0,.5-1l-.8-4.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.8-.7l-5.4-.6a.9.9,0,0,1-.7-.6,32.7,32.7,0,0,0-1.6-3.7.9.9,0,0,1,.1-.9l3.4-4.3a.9.9,0,0,0,0-1.1l-2.5-3.5a.9.9,0,0,0-1-.3l-5.1,1.8a.9.9,0,0,1-.9-.2,32.2,32.2,0,0,0-3.1-2.8.9.9,0,0,1-.3-.9l1.1-5.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.4-1l-3.8-2.1a.9.9,0,0,0-1.1.2l-3.8,3.8a.9.9,0,0,1-.9.2l-4-1.1a.9.9,0,0,1-.7-.7l-1.2-5.2a.9.9,0,0,0-.8-.7L77.4,31a.9.9,0,0,0-.9.6l-1.7,5a.9.9,0,0,1-.7.6l-4.1.7a.9.9,0,0,1-.9-.3l-3.3-4.1a.9.9,0,0,0-1-.3l-4,1.7a.9.9,0,0,0-.5.9l.6,5.2a.9.9,0,0,1-.4.9,32.7,32.7,0,0,0-3.4,2.5.9.9,0,0,1-.9.1l-4.7-2.2a.9.9,0,0,0-1,.2l-2.9,3.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.1,1.1L50,51.2a.9.9,0,0,1,0,1l-1.1,1.9-.9,1.9a.9.9,0,0,1-.8.5H41.9a.9.9,0,0,0-.8.6l-1.2,4.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.4,1l4.4,2.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.4.9,32.5,32.5,0,0,0-.2,4.2.9.9,0,0,1-.5.8l-4.7,2.3a.9.9,0,0,0-.5,1l.8,4.3a.9.9,0,0,0,.8.7l5.2.6a.9.9,0,0,1,.7.6,33,33,0,0,0,1.6,3.9.9.9,0,0,1-.1.9L45,89.4a.9.9,0,0,0,0,1.1L47.6,94a.9.9,0,0,0,1,.3l5-1.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.9.2,32.2,32.2,0,0,0,3.2,2.8.9.9,0,0,1,.3.9l-1.1,5.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.4,1l3.8,2.1a.9.9,0,0,0,1.1-.2l3.8-3.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.9-.2l4,1.1a.9.9,0,0,1,.7.7l1.2,5.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.8.7l4.3.2a.9.9,0,0,0,.9-.6l1.8-5.1a.9.9,0,0,1,.7-.6l4-.7a.9.9,0,0,1,.9.3l3.4,4.2a.9.9,0,0,0,1,.3l4-1.7a.9.9,0,0,0,.5-.9l-.6-5.4a.9.9,0,0,1,.4-.9A32.4,32.4,0,0,0,98.4,95a.9.9,0,0,1,.9-.1l4.9,2.3a.9.9,0,0,0,1-.2l2.9-3.3a.9.9,0,0,0,.1-1.1L105.3,88a.9.9,0,0,1,0-.9l1-1.7.9-1.8a.9.9,0,0,1,.8-.5h5.5a.9.9,0,0,0,.8-.6l1.2-4.2a.9.9,0,0,0-.4-1l-4.6-2.9a.9.9,0,0,1-.4-.9,32.2,32.2,0,0,0,.2-4A.9.9,0,0,1,110.8,68.5ZM92.7,77.1a16.1,16.1,0,1,1-6.5-21.9A16.1,16.1,0,0,1,92.7,77.1Z"/>
   </g>
 </g>
   <g id="gear-small">
     <path d="M47.9,38.1A18.8,18.8,0,0,1,43.3,46l3,4.8-3.7,2.8-3.8-4.1A18.8,18.8,0,0,1,30,51.8l-1.3,5.4-4.6-.6.2-5.5a18.8,18.8,0,0,1-7.8-4.6l-4.7,2.9L9,45.6l4.1-3.8a18.8,18.8,0,0,1-2.3-8.8L5.4,31.8,6,27.2l5.6.2a18.8,18.8,0,0,1,4.6-7.8l-3-4.8,3.7-2.8,3.8,4.2A18.8,18.8,0,0,1,29.4,14l1.3-5.5,4.6.6-.2,5.7a18.8,18.8,0,0,1,7.7,4.5l4.8-3L50.5,20l-4.2,3.9a18.8,18.8,0,0,1,2.3,8.7l5.5,1.3-.6,4.6ZM31.2,21.8a11.1,11.1,0,1,0,9.5,12.5A11.1,11.1,0,0,0,31.2,21.8Z" transform="translate(-0.3)" fill="#aadb1e" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
   </g>
   
     </svg>
```

Answer (score -2):

For those facing similar problems, it seems that moving the style declarations into the css and out of the inline `<path>` attribute solved the issue. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skqmmv75/2/).